# Grails 2.5.0 - access classes in maven dependency

Tags: grails, grails-2.5

I need to access some features of Jedis that aren't available in the Redis Plugin. I added `compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.8.0"` to my dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy, but my IDE is showing that the Jedis classes are still unavailable. How do I access those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your IDE that there is a change in your classpath structure.

Whichever IDE you are using, there should be a way to run any command. Like for IntelliJ: `Run` -> `Run Command`.

Open that dialog and run the command: `grails refresh-dependencies`

Comment: That did it. SO is making me wait to accept the answer.